# Why is list() not converting tuple in list?

Tags: python

I am learning python and in my course there is a code exemple to convert a tuple to a list. It is the following:

```
def afficher(*parametres, sep=' ', fin='\n'):

parametres = list(parametres)
for i, parametre in enumerate(parametres):
    parametres[i] = str(parametre)
chaine = sep.join(parametres)
chaine += fin
print(chaine, end='')
```

this fonction work perfectly is put in a file and then executed. To better understand the code I tried it line by line in the interactive python interpretator. If so convert tuple to list using list(), fails:

```
>>> t=(1,2,3)
>>> list(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Why is it not working in the interactive python interpretator? Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Have you called a variable `list`?

Comment: Try opening a new interpreter. It seems you must've reassigned `list` to something other than the built-in function.

Comment: `type(list)` should return: `<class 'type'>`. If you have any other result, then you have overridden the built-in `list` with a local variable.

Comment: (also, on your next question, use the `{}` button to format code after you paste it in - trying to manually indent code will lead to indentation errors on the code and reduce the quality of your question)

Comment: @Sayse  indeed you are right, it is alright now

Comment: @Zemens indeed you are right, it is alright now